# Initialization without recursion

Tags: c++, c, inheritance, recursion, struct

I'm trying to do a bit of refactoring and I am curious about how would you approach this problem.

Basically I'm trying to create an initialization function for each class. There are classes that inherit from some others, and i would like to use parent initialization function if possible. How would you address this?

I would like to use these structs with `memcpy` and maybe using also them with the keywords `align` and `__attribute__((packed))`; and they must be usable with `extern "C"`. I would exclude then constructors and destructors.

An example to explain:

```
struct A
  {
  int a;
  };

void initialize(A& a)  
  {
  a = 0;
  }

struct B : A
  {
  int b;
 };

void initialize(B& b)
  {
  initialize(b); // here I want void initialize(A& a), not recursion
  b = 0;
  };
```

Maybe I have to do some kind of cast? Ideally I'm looking a solution that does not create overhead.

Comment: After reading more carefully your question, you would like to use C. C++ is not meant for you it seems.

Comment: There are no references in `C`. And I don't think it has any kind of inheritance either.

Comment: I'm using C++ but in the future I could use them for a C API.

Comment: C also has neither function overloading nor inheritance.

Comment: `initialize(b)` -> `initialize(static_cast<A&>(b))`.

Comment: @Fureeish shouldn't that create a temporary copy?

Comment: No, no copies are being made. The only thing being created is a temporary reference to `b` of a type `A`. And the downvotes are probably caused by the reason that the question is slightly unclear, it doesn't seem to help future visitors or is generally of a poor quality. I didn't case any downvotes here, but I would assume those could be the reasons. Have you read [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: It is completely unclear how you want to "use them for a C API" in the future. The `B` you define in C++ is not C-compatible, and you would have to write completely different code to get a _similar_ structure in C (it won't really be the same). Anyway, @Fureeish already answered your question, unfortunately only in the comments instead of writing an answer. And no, it doesn't create a temporary copy, because that's a _reference_ to A.

Comment: @MaxLanghof originally I thought that the question is a little too unclear to make that an answer, but since no further edits were made and no clarification was given, I decided to provide an answer based on my comment. I do agree that answers belong in the answers section, not in the comment section.

Comment: @MaxLanghof you're right, for some reason I remember reading that inheriting from a struct in c++ without using virtual functions should preserve the POD C status. Am I wrong? about the temporary, well, ok no copy of A, but anyway a copy of the reference yes (a pointer copy) -> slower than the optimal solution (manually writing the assignments)

Comment: You make claims without arguments to back them up. Your `initialize` function takes a reference to `A`s and `B`s. Does that mean it's slower? No. Please, first benchmark, analyse generated assembly, for example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zyoQ89). Notice the generated assembly is **exactly the same** as if you just did `int main() { return 42; }`.

Comment: @Saturnu A struct can have inheritance and still be POD. But such struct definition cannot be used in a C program.

Comment: thank you for your reply. The fact is that in one case it should be guaranteed that no additional copy is created, in the second is not excluded. I am speaking just theoretically. If next year, someone, creates a compiler that does not do that optimization why should I modify that  code?

Comment: Well, then why would one use that compiler if it's worse in doing its job than the alternatives? Besides, this is getting off-topic. Let's cut the discussion here. I recommend you to read more about optimisations, about premature optimisations and about benchmarks :>

Comment: @eerorika yep, totally right.

Comment: @Fureeish replied below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `static_cast`.

In your code, the `initialize(b)` call will recurse infinitely, because `b` is better matched as `B&` than as `A&` (the argument of the function you want to call), thus the overload resolution picks the same function and recurs.

You specified that you want to initialise the `A` part of the `b` object. Why not tell that to the compiler? Tell it that you want to call `initialise` in it as though it was an `A`, like so:

```
initialize(static_cast<A&>(b));
```

As for your concern that you mentioned in the comment - no copies are being made here. If I used `static_cast<A>`, however, a temporary object would be created, but that's not the case. I am not casting `b` to an object of a type `A`. I am casting it to a *reference* of a type `A`, which will result in creation of temporary reference. Since `A&` matches with `A&` better than with `B&`, the first function will be chosen, thus avoiding the recursion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very clear. However, a copy of the reference will be created. It would be faster if you manually did the assignments

Comment: @Saturnu how much faster did you measure?

Comment: @Saturnu incorrect. Good compilers will likely optimise the temporary away. Are you aware of the fact that a simple `++i` is a copy, increment, then assign, if we're talking about pure assembly? Besides, what measurements did you take? *Why* do you claim that it will be slower? What are your benchmarks?

Comment: no benchmarks, I am speaking about theory here. What if you have this code in a loop and every microsecond was important, would you bet your life that that cast is not important?

Comment: @Saturnu • I believe the applicable theory is to:  profile, measure, and then adjust after assessing the impact.

Comment: @Eljay not if you're interested in write the code only once and not modifying it for the next N years

Comment: @Saturnu look at my recent comment below your post. Click [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zyoQ89) to see the generated assembly. Compare it to `int main() { return 42; }`. Be amazed how good modern compilers are at optimising. Never make assumptions on performance. EDIT: And yes, I **wil** bet my life that *the cast is not important*, because I checked the generated assembly and I see that it's even more efficient than assignment, because it's ignored all the way. These are called optimisations. You **never** should talk performance before you learn about them.

Comment: @Fureeish if I wanted you dead, I would write a compiler that following the C++ standard does not optimize that temp away. Luckily for you I am one of  the good guys there :D

Comment: And nobody would use that compiler, so I would still be perfectly safe. But if you wish to use worse compilers, then the problem of optimisation is at your end.

Comment: @Saturnu if your life depends on a single pointer sized copy, then you need to write assembly; Not C and very much not C++.

Comment: I know about optimization is the root of..  but I know also about "Don’t pessimize prematurely." Just saying that this is the case in my opinion. If you know you have to write a library that must not be modified , must not produce any performance penalties, and will for sure compiled by many many different compilers, including some that will not have good optimization options (maybe embedded or some new ones), it's better to write the code once, being sure that the code you're writing is the most efficient one. Having said this, I thank you again for you reply and I wish you a nice weekend

Comment: @eerorika good point, however, the guy that holds the knife allows you to write only C++ code ;)

Comment: @Saturnu For any piece of code you write, I can write a compiler that makes _only that exact code_ take 1000000 times longer than normal. In fact, this is extremely easy to do (wrap e.g. clang but check the source [or AST] for exact match before passing it, if it matches add a bunch of garbage to waste time). This is incredibly irrelevant to performance concerns. And "does it optimize away the temporary reference?" is so deep into premature optimization that I don't know what you think "premature optimization" means.

Comment: @Fureeish I hate to add the caveat, but C++ potentially has to adjust pointers (and references) when converting to base class ones (certainly if there is more than one base class) - clearly, two different non-empty base class objects can't be stored at the same location. That's most likely still irrelevant because that's the compiler's business to work out and optimize, but it's not guaranteed to be free. I mean, it's not like there is a more efficient way to do this in the first place, but it's probably worth noting that this is a """"cost"""" of inheritance.

Comment: @MaxLanghof interesting observation yes. My point is that, under the assumptions of my previous comment, it's better to be sure to write the code that most likely will be compiled in the fastest way by most of compilers. I just wanted to know if there was a pattern that allows to do that thing in a way in a sure faster way. Probably 99.9% of times this will not be relevant, but in the remaining 0.01 % of times maybe yes

Comment: @Saturnu That pattern is "write assembly code optimized for your target platform". And hope that modern compilers don't beat you because they still know that platform better than you. Once and for all: **Don't assume that some pattern is slow just because it involves an extra step in your mental model.** If you want _the fastest_ code, you have to _measure_. Reasoning about it from the outside gets you **nowhere**.

Comment: @MaxLanghof thank you again for your feedback, everything is worth to know. Have to go now, have a nice weekend as well